# Errors with type variables. Can you guys help me make my code work?

Tags: python, json

I am new at python and i need some help to make my code work, i am having some errors with the type of variables like: "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable"
and
"TypeError: can't convert type 'str' to numerator/denominator"
I have asked some questions in here about that, but i cant make the code to work. links of the questions:
[TypeError: can't convert type 'str' to numerator/denominator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63847926/typeerror-cant-convert-type-str-to-numerator-denominator)
[Python Error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63724359/python-error-typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices-not-str)

My code is the following:

```
year_codes = ["2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020"]

    month_codes = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"]

    city_codes = ["1111609", "1120303", "11A1312", "11D1714", "11E0402", "16D0105", "16E0603", "16F1009", "16G1823",
                  "16H0502", "16J0907", "1701106", "1701512", "1840205", "1851416", "1861214", "1870705", "1500805"]

    valor_anual = [0][0]

    for city_code in city_codes:

        for year_code in year_codes:
            valor_mensal_aux = []
            for month_code in month_codes:

                url_imob = Request(
                    "https://www.ine.pt/ine/json_indicador/pindica.jsp?op=2&varcd=0010042&Dim1=S3A" + year_code + \
                    month_code + "&Dim2=" + city_code + "&Dim3=T&lang=PT", headers={'User-Agent': 'XYZ/3.0'})
                json_date = year_code + month_code
                response = urlopen(url_imob)
                data = json.loads(response.read())
                valor_mensal_aux.append(int(data[0]['Dados'][json_date][0]['valor']))

            valor_anual[data[0]['Dados'][json_date][0]['geodsg']][year_code] = statistics.mean(valor_mensal_aux)

            python_imob = Imob(year_code, valor_anual[city_code][year_code], data['DataUltimoAtualizacao'],
                               data['Dados'][json_date]['geodsg'])
            session.add(python_imob)  
            session.commit()
            session.close()
            imobs = session.query(Imob).all()
```

I have errors with my arrays, the "valor_anual" and the "valor_mensal"

one of the JSON's is the following:

```
[ {
  "IndicadorCod" : "0010042",
  "IndicadorDsg" : "Valor mediano de avaliação bancária (€/ m²) por Localização geográfica (Município - 2013) e Tipo de construção; Mensal - INE, Inquérito à avaliação bancária na habitação",
  "MetaInfUrl" : "https://www.ine.pt/bddXplorer/htdocs/minfo.jsp?var_cd=0010042&lingua=PT",
  "DataExtracao" : "2020-06-29T15:55:51.640+01:00",
  "DataUltimoAtualizacao" : "2020-06-29",
  "UltimoPref" : "Maio de 2020",
  "Dados" : {
    "202005" : [ {
      "geocod" : "1701106",
      "geodsg" : "Lisboa",
      "dim_3" : "T",
      "dim_3_t" : "Total",
      "valor" : "3084"
    } ]
  }
} ]
```

So basically i want to get data from JSON's from [www.ine.pt](http://www.ine.pt) that's why i cycled the url string with different codes to have different JSON's. I need to get the value "valor" for each month and use the mean to transform it to year value, but i need to know which value corresponds to each year and to each city, like im trying to with the "valor_anual" array. My "geodsg" variable from JSON contains the name of a city, each iterarion of the city code cycle. Can you guys help me to make this code work? i'm trying to make it work for some time now and i cant go anywhere from here..
Thank you so much and sorry for the long question

Answer (score 1):

'''

1. Make sure whatever dados date is present in data response and if does not exist handle with ease
2. You don't need a 2-D array to store your country value..you can store it in local variable if there is no further need of it or if you need further refernce you can have a list of dict
   **I'm attaching a method from where you can fetch data from list of dict using any key
   '''

   '''
   data- dataset
   key- dict key you want to use the first record
   value - value that needs to be searched
   '''

def getDataFromListOfDict(data, key, value):
for i in data:
if(i[key] == value):
return i

```
    def getRequest(year_code, month_code, city_code):
        string =  "https://www.ine.pt/ine/json_indicador/pindica.jsp?op=2&varcd=0010042&Dim1=S3A"
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'XYZ/3.0'}
        month_qoute = "&Dim2="
        city_qoute = "&Dim3=T&lang=PT"
    
        url_imob = Request((string+year_code + "/" + month_code + month_qoute + city_code + city_qoute), headers)
        json_date = year_code + month_code
        response = urlopen(url_imob)
        data = json.loads(response.read())
        return data[0]
    
    
    def getValor(data_item, json_date):
        try:
            return int(data_item['Dados'][json_date][0]['valor'])
        except:
            return 0
    
    def getGeodsg(data_item, json_date):
        try:
            return int(data_item['Dados'][json_date][0]['geodsg'])
        except:
            return 0
    
    def getMean(array):
        from statistics import mean
        return mean(array)
    
    
    def execute():
        year_codes = ["2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020"]
    
        month_codes = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"]
    
        city_codes = ["1111609", "1120303", "11A1312", "11D1714", "11E0402", "16D0105", "16E0603", "16F1009", "16G1823",
                      "16H0502", "16J0907", "1701106", "1701512", "1840205", "1851416", "1861214", "1870705", "1500805"]
    
        valor_anual = []
    
        # assuming this is initialize as a empty list
        valor_mensal_aux = []
    
        for city_code in city_codes:
    
            for year_code in year_codes:
                valor_mensal_aux = []
                for month_code in month_codes:
    
                    json_date = year_code + month_code
    
                    first_data = getRequest(year_code, month_code, city_code) 
                    valor_mensal_aux.append(getValor(first_data, json_date))
                    internal_dict = {
                        'index' : getGeodsg(first_data, json_date),
                        'year_code' : year_code,
                        'mean' : getMean(valor_mensal_aux)
                    }
                    #  for other reference add a dictionary to a list
                    valor_mensal_aux.append(internal_dict)
             
                # python_imob = Imob(year_code, valor_anual[city_code][year_code], data['DataUltimoAtualizacao'],data['Dados'][json_date]['geodsg'])
                # Above is you have written and missing data[0] and ['Dados'][json_date][0]
                    python_imob = Imob(year_code, internal_dict['mean'], data['DataUltimoAtualizacao'],getGeodsg(first_data, json_date))
    
                    session.add(python_imob)  
                    session.commit()
                    session.close()
                    imobs = session.query(Imob).all()
    
    
    execute()
```

Comment: how can i re write this in order to work? i am new ,guys, i need some help with this

Comment: i will implement it now, and text you back, thank you so much for the help!

Comment: in the line:    ​first_data = getRequest(year_code, month_code, city_code
I get the error: TypeError: can't concat str to bytes

Comment: is it necessary to have a month quote ??